# Python for loop - adding function

Tags: python-3.x

1. Create a list called ‘cat_home’. Populate the list with five cats.
2. Loop through the list. On each iteration make each cat meow, fight and eat.

so i have created step 1 which is

```
cat_home = ["Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3", "Cat4", "Cat5"]
```

then i have created the loop:

```
for x in cat_home:
    print(x)
```

but i have no idea how to proceed onto step 2

**functions**:

```
def meow (self):
  print(self.name, "says meow")

def fight (self):
  print("scratch, arrgg, wrahh", self.name, "is fighting")
  self.lives -=1
  print(self.name, "now only has", self.lives,"lives")

def eat (self):
  print("munch munch, yum yum!", self.name, "is eating")
  self.lives +=1
  print(self.name, "now  has", self.lives,"lives")`
```

Comment: Perhaps each `Cat` should be a `class` instead of a simple string, if you're using `self` in the functions/methods?

Answer (score 0):

How this works is each function takes in one parameter, `catpos` or the position in the home. The `for` loop then cycles through, adding one to x each time and changing the cat's position and which cat is selected. `sublife` and `addlife` are used inside of other functions.

```
cat_home = ["Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3", "Cat4", "Cat5"]
catpos = 0
lives = [9,9,9,9,9]
cat = cat_home[catpos]

def sublife(catpos):
    newlife = int(lives[catpos]) - 1
    lives[catpos] = newlife
    print(cat +" now only has",lives[catpos],"lives.")

def addlife(catpos):
    newlife = int(lives[catpos]) + 1
    lives[catpos] = newlife
    print(cat +" now has",lives[catpos],"lives.")

def meow(catpos):
    print(cat+" says meow.")

def fight(catpos):
    print("Scratch, arrgg, wrahh " + cat +" is fighting.")
    sublife(catpos)

def eat(catpos):
    print("Munch munch, yum yum! "+cat+" is eating.")
    addlife(catpos)

for x in range(len(cat_home)):
    fight(x - 1)
    eat(x - 1)
    meow(x - 1)
```